# Shared customer system architecture

Tags: database-design, web-applications, server, architecture

Bit of a general question about how a system should be architectured.

I am thinking about building a web system that allows businesses to login and manage their customers (within a specific market).

Now I want them to just go to our website and click the login, once they do this then they will log into their account and see their customers data.

The problem I have is with how the database/application should be structured.

First option could be to host ‘their’ system on their own server but this is costly.

Second option is to host all in the same database and define in the customers table which company they belong to and code the query to only look for customers that have the same company id.

Third option is to have the same application files hosted on the same web server but define the logic per customer to then connect to their own database (hosted on the same server but under a different database).

The second option would be the easiest but I don’t like that lots of different businesses customer data is in the same table, to me it should be separate.

So the question is what is the best way to architect such a system to provide the best security whilst also keeping costs down, e.g. not having a server for each company?

Answer (score 0):

A database server can have multiple databases on it. All separated by different users.

You could setup a database cluster (for high availability) and give each installation it's one database in the cluster.

Also look into docker and rancher as a virtualisation platform. You could launch many sites on the same hardware while separating them all in different networks.